# Can we use cocos2D demo applications in game?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want to use an Demo application used in Cocos2D 0.9.3 to my demo game application?

is there any way to use those application directly or I have to make that application manually?

Please help.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say yes as it says in the license file you can use the "Software" without restriction and it says the "Software" includes the software and associated documentation files (which the demo applications are a part of).  Just make sure you include this notice with it - Always give credit where credit is due.

> cocos2d for iPhone:
>   http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org
>
> Copyright (c) 2008-2010 - (see each
>   file to see the different copyright
>   owners)
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of
>   charge, to any person obtaining a copy
>   of this software and associated
>   documentation files (the "Software"),
>   to deal in the Software ***without
>   restriction, including without
>   limitation the rights to use, copy,
>   modify, merge, publish, distribute,
>   sublicense, and/or sell copies of the
>   Software***, and to permit persons to
>   whom the Software is furnished to do
>   so, subject to the following
>   conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this
>   permission notice shall be included in
>   all copies or substantial portions of
>   the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS",
>   WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS
>   OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED
>   TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
>   FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
>   NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
>   AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE
>   FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
>   LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF
>   CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
>   FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
>   SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS
>   IN THE SOFTWARE.

Comment: You only need to include the license if you release the source code, it doesn't need to be in the app bundle though.